# How to check if plugin is compatible with Wordpress Version?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Is there a function in wordpress framework which makes this check (without `get_bloginfo("version")`)? Should work like this:

```
wp_version_is_equal_or_greater_than("3.5");
```

Comment: What's your question? Why can't you use that method? What do you need to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can make that function yourself:

```
function wp_version_is_equal_or_greater_than( $version ) {
    if(bloginfo( 'version' ) >= $version) return true;
    return false;
}
```