# WordPress get_template_part pass variable

Tags: wordpress, variables

Is there a way of passing a variable to get_template_part() in wordpress:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'element-templates/front', 'top' ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'element-templates/front', 'main' ); ?>
```

In the front-top.php and front-main.php (which the above is calling) I need to access numeric variables (a different one for each section). Is there a way of passing a variable to each of the calls above?

Thank you

Answer (score 142, accepted):

### Using WordPress 5.5+

As of WordPress 5.5, passing variables via get_template_part is part of [core](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/17/passing-arguments-to-template-files-in-wordpress-5-5/).

> Starting in WordPress 5.5, the template loading functions will now
> allow additional arguments to be passed through to the matched
> template file using a new $args parameter.

```
get_template_part( string $slug, string $name = null, array $args = null  )
```

Example:

```php
  get_template_part( 'template-parts/featured-image', null,
    array( 
     'class' => 'featured-home',
     'data'  => array(
       'size' => 'large',
       'is-active' => true,
      )
     ) 
    );
```

and then in the included file (i.e. `template-parts/featured-image.php`), you can either just display the variables (as per above example):

```php
    if ( $args['class'] ) {
      echo $args['class'];
    }
```

or

```
echo $args['data']['size'];
```

Alternatively, setup defaults first, using `wp_parse_args`:

```php
// Setup defaults
$array_defaults = array( 
    'class' => 'featured',
    'data' => array(
        'size' => 'medium',
        'is-active' => false,
     )
); 
    
$args = wp_parse_args($args, $array_defaults );


<div class="widget <?php echo esc_html( $args['class'] ); ?>">
        <?php echo esc_html( $args['data']['size'] ); ?>
</div>
```

To be backwards compatible in your theme, you should probably also check the [current WordPress version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322466/how-to-check-if-plugin-is-compatible-with-wordpress-version).

---

### Using `set_query_vars`

The original answer to this question was to use `set_query_var`

In your theme:

```
<?php
set_query_var( 'my_var_name', 'my_var_value' );
get_template_part( 'template-parts/contact' );
?>
```

In the template part:

```
<?php
$newValue = get_query_var( 'my_var_name' );
if ( $newValue ) {
  // do something
}
?>
```

Comment: Note that the var stays in the globals. You will need to set_query_var('my_var_name', false); after the get_template_part call or else you will see same vars in the next call of the template.

Comment: Unfortunately the `$args` parameter isn't run through `extract()` so you'll need to do `echo $args['foo']` in the template instead of just `echo $foo`. I wish there was an option to extract the args too.

Comment: Hi, there. I'm kind of new to wordpress coding and I've been trying to get a variable from another file. I have this variable $final_cat_url in /custom/last-category.php that I want to reuse in customtemplate.php. 

Based on what you explained above, I tried to use the following code in customtemplate.php, but it's not working.

`get_template_part( 'custom/last-category', null, array('my_final_cat_url'=> $final_cat_url)); 
echo $args['my_final_cat_url'];`

Can you help me with that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jay You should open your own question really, but try using `print_r($args)` to see what the `$args` variable is moving between templates.

Comment: The function `set_query_var` works well, but creates an extra GET request. So it would be better performance wise to pass the variable as the third parameter of the `get_template_part` function.

Comment: the mentioned `wp_parse_args` default mechanism doesn't work well for the nested `data` items. they get overwritten by not existent args without leaving defaults. useful is something like `$props = wp_parse_args($args['data'], $array_defaults );`. of course not when nested another level deeper inside `data`.

Answer (score 6):

The core `get_template_part()` function doesn't support the passing of variables. It only accepts two parameters, slug and name. While there is no built-in solution to this problem, the best approach is to create a function that closely mimics `get_template_part()` to handle it.

Normally I would create a function that just takes the name of the template file and the variables I want to pass in as an array. In your example however, you're using both arguments for `get_template_part()` already which means you'll need a slightly more complex function. I'm going to post both versions below.

## Simplified Version - Name (slug) and Data

```
function wpse_get_partial($template_name, $data = []) {
    $template = locate_template($template_name . '.php', false);

    if (!$template) {
        return;
    }

    if ($data) {
        extract($data);
    }

    include($template);
}
```

Usage example: `wpse_get_partial('header-promotion', ['message' => 'Example message']);`

This would load up a file named `header-promotion.php` with `$message` available inside of it. Since the second parameter is an array, you can pass in as many variables as you need.

### Copy of get_template_part - adding a third parameter

If you don't need both `$slug` and `$name` when you call `get_template_part()`, you probably want the simplified version. For those that do, here's the more complex option.

```
function wpse_get_template_part($slug, $name = null, $data = []) {
    // here we're copying more of what get_template_part is doing.
    $templates = [];
    $name = (string) $name;

    if ('' !== $name) {
        $templates[] = "{$slug}-{$name}.php";
    }

    $templates[] = "{$slug}.php";

    $template = locate_template($templates, false);

    if (!$template) {
        return;
    }

    if ($data) {
        extract($data);
    }

    include($template);
}
```

Usage example: `wpse_get_template_part('header-promotion', 'top', [$message => 'Example message']);`

Neither function is a perfect copy of `get_template_part()`. I've skipped all of the extra filters the core function uses for the sake of simplicity.

### What about globals or query vars

- Globals are pretty commonplace in WordPress but are generally best avoided. They will work but start to get messy when you use the same template part more than once on a single page.
- Query vars (`get_query_var()` / `set_query_var()`) aren't made for that purpose. It's a hacky workaround that can introduce unintended side-effects.

Answer (score 4):

As of WordPress 5.5, you're be able to achieve this using the following method:

```
<?php
get_template_part( 
    'my-template-name', 
    null, 
    array( 
        'my_data' => array(
            'var_one' => 'abc',
            'var_two' => true,
        )
    )
);
```

In your template, you can then parse the date and escape it in the following way:

```
<?php
$args = wp_parse_args(
    $args,
    array(
        'my_data' => array(
            'var_one' => 'xyz', // default value
            'var_two' => false, // default value
        )
    )
);
?>
<?php echo esc_html( $args['my_data']['var_one'] ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can pass data to tempalte part via Global varible

like this
$var = 'smoe data here';

```
<?php get_template_part( 'element-templates/front', 'top' ); ?>
```

then in your template part file use

```
<?php 
global $var; 
echo $var; // smoe data here
?>
```

Comment: You have to set the $var to be global on the main file also!

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned by `thetwopct` - since WP 5.5, you can pass `$args` to the `get_template_part` function like so:

```
$value_of_first  = 'pizza';
$value_of_second = 'hamburger';
$value_of_first  = 'milkshake';

$args = array(
  'first'  => $value_of_first,
  'second' => $value_of_second,
  'third'  => $value_of_third,
)
get_template_part( 'element-templates/front', 'top', $args );
```

then, in `element-templates/front-top.php` get the vars like so:

```
[
  'first'  => $value_of_first,
  'second' => $value_of_second,
  'third'  => $value_of_third,
] = $args;
echo 'I like to eat '.$value_of_first.' and '.$value_of_second.' and then drink '.$value_of_third.';
// will print "I like to eat pizza and hamburger and then drink milkshake"
```

**Note:** the method described above for getting the vars in the template file uses associative array restructuring, available only from PHP 7.1. You can also do something like:

```
echo 'I like to eat '.$args[value_of_first].' and ...
```

Answer (score -3):

A quick and dirty workaround can be made using [PHP Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php):

**In your theme:**

```
define("A_CONSTANT_FOR_TEMPLATE_PART", "foo");
get_template_part("slug", "name" );
```

Now in slug-name.php template file you can use the `A_CONSTANT_FOR_TEMPLATE_PART` constant. Be sure not override system constants by using a custom prefix for your constant name.

**In your template part file:**

```
echo A_CONSTANT_FOR_TEMPLATE_PART;
```

You should see "foo".

Comment: To explain the downvotes: While this does work, you are putting data in the global space. That itself can lead to a lot of side effects.

Comment: In a "plain" PHP project constants are obviously available in whole global space. It's (or it has been) a common practice, well tested and documented.
Why treat a "wordpress PHP project" in so different manner?

Comment: It's not common practice to bring data into the global space, but within the smallest scope you can have the data in.